# How to combine multiple Endpoint in finch

Tags: scala, finch

I am trying to compose multiple Endpoint together when starting the http server.
Multiple Endpoints are defined like this:

```
  val foo = get("foo") { Ok("bar") }
  val test = get("test") { Ok("test") }
```

This code is working

```
  foo :+: test
```

However, this code doesnt work.

```
  List(foo, test).reduceLeft(_ :+: _)
```

The error is

```
 type mismatch;
 found   : io.finch.Endpoint[shapeless.:+:[String,shapeless.:+:[String,shapeless.CNil]]]
 required: io.finch.Endpoint[String]
 val controllers = List(foo, test).reduce(_ :+: _)
                                         ^
```

I dont quite understand why `reduce` wont work here and what is the best practice to combine Endpoint in Finch

Comment: May I suggest you to look at my project: https://github.com/akozhemiakin/finchrich
It may help you to combine endpoints in a less verbose way.

Answer (score 3):

> why reduce wont work here

If you have `x: Endpoint[String]`, `y: Endpoint[String]` then `x :+: y` returns a `Endpoint[Coproduct[String, String]]`<sup>1</sup> - importantly it is *not* the same type as `x` or `y`

Take a look at the `reduce`<sup>2</sup> signature:

```
List[A].reduce[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

You have a `List[Endpoint[String]]` - the `op` must take arguments `x: Endpoint[String]`, `y: Endpoint[String]` and return a `Endpoint[String]` - but `:+:` will return `Endpoint[Coproduct[String, String]]`

> best practice to combine Endpoint in Finch

I haven't used Finch but all the examples in the repo simply combine the endpoints with `:+:`

https://github.com/finagle/finch/blob/e3a62bf9a1cb26af40af428dd9be8b2dc3339c44/examples/src/main/scala/io/finch/todo/Main.scala#L83

```
getTodos :+: postTodo :+: deleteTodo :+: deleteTodos :+: patchTodo
```

Collections (like `List`) are super useful if you are going to manipulate the elements at runtime - is that a use case you need to support? I've generally found that I know all my routes at compile time

---

<sub>1. Some liberties were taken with the `Coproduct` type signature - `Coproduct[String, String]` rather than `shapeless.:+:[String, shapeless.:+:[String, shapeless.CNil]]`</sub>

<sub>2. A similar argument holds for `reduceLeft`</sub>